# Loading gif fades out before the image completely loads, why is that?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, fetch-api

I am testing out a dummy site to work on fetching data from, in this case the NASA API. I am pull the data and outputting the title, date, author, explanation, and the url of the day's astronomical image. Everything is outputting perfectly so I'm assuming I'm fetching everything correctly.

My other task is having a loading gif run on top of it all until all my data outputs on the DOM. The text is very quick but the image takes a while. I have made my gif fadeOut smoothly, however it fades out quicker than the image loads. I'm assuming it's because I am fetching the data but I am somewhat new at this so I'm not sure how to fix it.

I've been playing around with ComponentDidMount() and window.eventListener("load", () => {}) but I think the way I'm using it isn't loading everything in the right order. Any tips would be much appreciated!

By the way, I am using React!

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DataOutput from './Components/DataOutput'
import LoadingGif from './Components/LoadingGif'

const API_KEY = 'VuPavaR3ZqkuzGivHZJnOPy3KDpjiARyhJsdvcjt'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    author : undefined,
    date : undefined,
    explanation : undefined,
    title : undefined, 
    url : undefined,
  }

  getNASAData = async () => {
    const getData = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
    const data = await getData.json();
    this.setState({
        author : data.copyright,
        date : data.date,
        explanation : data.explanation,
        title : data.title, 
        url : data.url,
    })
  }

componentDidMount(){
  this.getNASAData();
}

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="App">
       <LoadingGif/>
       <DataOutput 
        title={this.state.title}
        url={this.state.url}
        explanation={this.state.explanation}
        date={this.state.date}
        author={this.state.author}
       />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

DataOutput.js

```
import React from 'react'

const DataOutput = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row mt-5">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                <div className="row mt-5">
                    <div className="col-6">
                        <img className="NasaImg" src={props.url} alt={props.title}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-6">
                        <h2>{props.author}</h2>
                        <h3>{props.date}</h3>
                        <p>{props.explanation}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DataOutput
```

LoadingGif.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Cat from '../catLoading.gif'

const LoadingGif = () => {

    window.addEventListener("load", () =>{
        const loader = document.getElementById('loader');
        console.log(loader);
        loader.className += " hidden";
    })

    return (
        <div id="loader" className="loader">
            <img className="catImg" src={Cat} alt="cat loading"/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LoadingGif
```

And the CSS, just in case...

```
.NasaImg{
  width:100%;
}

.loader{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:999;
  width: 400px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:rgb(223, 217, 224);
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.loader.hidden{
  animation: fadeOut 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.catImg{
  width:400px;
}


@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code is gonna work - there are multiple problems with it:

first of all window's `load` event is probably not going to fire for your data request.

secondly - attaching an event listener is a "side effect" you should wrap it inside a `useEffect`. (however we shouldn't be using that event here) https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

In `React` - try to avoid using `document.find***` or other helpers to get DOM nodes (again, usually you don't need to change dom nodes directly) If you need to have access to a DOM node, use `ref`. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

and in React in 99.99% cases you shouldn't modify DOM directly - let `React` handle that - you should provide react components with proper `state` and let your components render directly.

---

OK how do we solve your problem here?

> loading gif run on top of it all until all my data outputs on the DOM

So from this I think we should:

1. have a state flag (let's say `loaded`) that tracks if data has been fetched.
2. hide the loading animation when `loaded` is true. (and assuming we are still doing that with css)

How do we do that?

So in your loader component, it should take a prop `hidden` - when it is true, we add the `hidden` class to the loader - so it is going to look like this:

```
const LoadingGif = ({ hidden }) => {
  return (
    <div id="loader" className={`loader ${hidden ? 'hidden' : ''}`}>
      <img
       //...
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And in your `App` add a field to your state to track if your data has been loaded:

```
state = {
  // ... your other states
  loaded: false
};
```

when your fetch completes, make sure to update it to `true`

```
    const data = await getData.json();
      this.setState({
        author: data.copyright,
        date: data.date,
        explanation: data.explanation,
        title: data.title,
        url: data.url,
        loaded: true  // here
      });
```

in your render, provide that `loaded` state to your loader component as a prop:

```
// it is hidden when `loaded` is true
<LoadingGif hidden={this.state.loaded} />
```

Putting it together:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/patient-resonance-s3si9

Comment: by the way it still fades pretty fast because the network request is pretty fast.